# HOCON escape double quotes

Tags: string, configuration, escaping, hocon

HOCON playground: https://hocon-playground.herokuapp.com/

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

I need end result to be:

{
    "HOCON" : "{host =~ "hi*"}",
    "lbid" : "hi*"
}

What I am getting is:

**Input:**

lbid="hi*"
HOCON = "{host =~ \""${lbid}"\"}"

**Output:**
{
    "HOCON" : "{host =~ \"hi*\"}",
    "lbid" : "hi*"
}

Can someone tell me how to escape double quotes in presence of multiple double quotes? I need the entire string inside double quotes like ("hi*").

hi value is also coming from a variable. This is making things little bit complicated and not providing the expected output.

Comment: The "end result" requested is not valid JSON. You can't have unescaped double quotes within a JSON string.  The escaped double quotes get turned into plain double quotes when the JSON string value is parsed by a JSON parser.